# Retrive WMS layer info in a geoportal using Open Layers

Tags: openlayers, getfeatureinfo, html5, viewer

I've created a viewer using Open Layers 6. Within the script, I've got the following code to retrieve the info of a WMS layer, and it works fine, added directly into the html file within the  section.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = vista.getResolution();
        var url = wmsLayer3.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:25830', {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) document.getElementById('info').data = url;
    });
```

When clicking, it opens a window below the map with the requested information

[image]

However, when I try to prepare a more elaborated geoportal in html and use an independent .js file for the viewer script, the click function returns the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined
<anonymous> visualizador.js:133
dispatchEvent Target.js:114
handleMapBrowserEvent PluggableMap.js:850
dispatchEvent Target.js:114
clickTimeoutId_ MapBrowserEventHandler.js:128
setTimeout handler*e.prototype.emulateClick_    
MapBrowserEventHandler.js:123
handlePointerUp_ MapBrowserEventHandler.js:169
Z events.js:58
handlePointerDown_ MapBrowserEventHandler.js:200
Z events.js:58
e MapBrowserEventHandler.js:88
handleTargetChanged_ PluggableMap.js:964
dispatchEvent Target.js:114
notify Object.js:160
set Object.js:180
setProperties Object.js:193
e PluggableMap.js:319
e Map.js:85
<anonymous> visualizador.js:10
```

This is the script for the viewer (visualizador.js)

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25830","+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

    var vista = new ol.View({
        projection: "EPSG:25830",
        center: [35275, 3990117],
        zoom: 5.4,
        });
        
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: vista,
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend ([
            new ol.control.MousePosition ({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
            }),
            new ol.control.ScaleLine (),
            new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
            ]),
        });
        

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector ({
        type:'base',
        title: 'Vacía'
    });

    
    var wmsLayer2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        type:  'base',
        title: 'IGN Base',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base',
            params: {LAYERS: 'IGNBaseTodo', FORMAT: 'image/png'},
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.ign.es'><img src='imgs/ign.jpg'></a>"
            })
        });

    var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        type:  'base',
        title: 'PNOA',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/pnoa-ma',
            params: {LAYERS: 'OI.OrthoimageCoverage', FORMAT: 'image/png'},
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.ign.es'><img src='imgs/ign.jpg'></a>"
        })
    });
        
    var wmsLayer3 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Atlas primavera',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/atlas/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'prueba', format: "image/png"},
            gutter: 350,
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.seo.org'> <img src='imgs/logo.png'></a>"
        })
    });

    var wmsLayer4 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Gorrión molinero',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/atlas/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'passmo', format: "image/png"},
            gutter: 350,
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.seo.org'> <img src='imgs/logo.png'></a>"
        })
    });

    var wmsLayer5 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'IBA Pen_Bal',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iba/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'iba_pen_bal', format: "image/png"},
            gutter: 250,
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.seo.org'> <img src='imgs/logo.png'></a>"
        })
    });

    var wmsLayer6 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'IBA Canarias',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iba/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'iba_canar', format: "image/png"},
            gutter: 250,
            attributions: "<a href='https://www.seo.org'> <img src='imgs/logo.png'></a>"
        })
    });

    var group1 =
    new ol.layer.Group ({
        title: 'Capas Base',
        layers: [vectorLayer, wmsLayer, wmsLayer2],
    });

    var group2 =
    new ol.layer.Group ({
        title: 'Atlas',
        layers: [wmsLayer4, wmsLayer3],
    });

    var group3 =
    new ol.layer.Group ({
        title: 'IBA',
        layers: [wmsLayer5, wmsLayer6],
    });

    map.addLayer(group1);
    map.addLayer(group2);
    map.addLayer(group3);

    map.addControl (new ol.control.OverviewMap({
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile(wmsLayer2.getProperties())],
    }));

    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher ({
        tipLabel: 'Capas'
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

    map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {

  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  const viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
  const url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
evt.coordinate,
viewResolution,
'EPSG:25830',
{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}
 );
  if (url) {
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((html) => {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
  });
 }
});
```

And this is the html code for the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>IDE_SEO/BirdLife</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imgs/favicon.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol/ol.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ol/ol-layerswitcher.css">
<script src="ol/ol.js"></script>
<script src="ol/ol-layerswitcher.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
<style> 
    .ol-overviewmap {
        bottom: 32px;
    }

    .ol-scale-line{
        background: rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.8);
    }

    .layer-switcher .panel{
        background-color:rgba(0, 60, 136, 0.5);
        color: white;
        font-family: "Arial, Verdana, Courier New";
    }

    .ol-mouse-position{
        color: rgba(0, 60, 136, 1.0);
        background-color: white;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <section id="top_logos">    
        <figure id="logo_seo">
            <img src="imgs/logo_seo.png" alt="SEO/BirdLife">
        </figure>
        <h1>
            Geoportal de SEO/BirdLife
        </h1>
        <figure id="logo_ide">
            <img src="imgs/logo_ide.png" alt="IDE SEO/BirdLife">
        </figure>
    </section>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicios.html">Servicios OGC</a></li>
            <li><a href="visualizador.html">Visor</a></li>
            <!--li><a href="http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/"></a>Buscador</li-->
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <figure id="cabecera">
        <img src="imgs/cabecera.jpg" alt="grullas">
    </figure>
</header>

<section id="componentesIDE">
    <section id="map" class="visualizador"> 
    </section>

    <section id="info"> &nbsp;
    </section>
</section>
<footer>
    <section id="creditospie">
        <p>
            © 2022 SEO/BirdLife
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="logospie">
        <a href="http://www.opengeospatial.org/"><img src="imgs/ogc.gif" alt="OGC"></a>
        <a href="http://www.idee.es/"><img src="imgs/idee.gif" alt="IDEE"></a>
        <a href="http://inspire.jrc.europa.eu/"><img src="imgs/inspire.gif" alt="INSPIRE"></a>
    </section>
</footer>

<script src="js/visualizador.js"></script>
```

What code would be needed to show the requested information?

Comment: I would start with checking whether it goes inside your click function code or not ? If not, do you see any error on developer console of the browser ?

Comment: Without seeing your non working code it's impossible to answer. What exactly is "unable to open the window"? Any errors in the browser debugger console. Please edit your question and add missing details.

Comment: Edited, as suggested.

Comment: Relevant code is still missing.

Comment: Edited, to include the code

Answer (score 3):

Your error says that the view is not defined. Somewhere in the code that you DIDN'T post, you should define it or store it in the correct variable. In the posted code, the view is stored in a variable called vista I guess as you call `vista.getResolution();`.

Otherwise, if you are looking for help with the code that does not work, you should post the code that does not work, not the working example:)

EDIT:

It should be `const viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (vista.getResolution());`